# disable a textbox in another page PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

is there any way to disable a text input in another page ? I searched but I didn't find any thing !

to explain

I have this page that is mostly html text inputs
and I load it in a main page if the user press a button, sometimes I need one of the textbox to be disable and sometimes not

The question is, is there any function in php or javascript or ajax that can help me disable one of the textbox from the main page ?

Comment: You're question is not very clear. It would be helpful to post some code to understand your scenario. In particular, what are the distinct pages you are referring to? Also, what is the relationship between the button and the textboxes that would influence whether they are disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```
$('.myinput').prop('disabled', true);
```

There are basically two cases:

1. In case you do it in PHP you have to submit either post or get data to the script which displays the input
2. In case you do it which JS or jQuery there must be a condition in your script that tells the input when to be displayed and when not